# How To Trace The Line Of A Print With The Nozzle (With No Plastic Printed)

Tags: ultimaker-cura, calibration, bltouch

I want to calibrate my printer for my new BLTouch (Ender 3 using Marlins 1.1.9), every time I adjust the values in the configuration.h and send it to the printer I end up having to wait for the nozzle and the bed to heat up, it also wastes plastic. 
Is there a way to take out the values in the code that make the extruder turn without causing any damage.
the slicer that I am using is Cura and the print that I want to trace is [this calibration crosshair.](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2280529/) Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which values? You only need to print it once, measure your offset and send adjustments over USB (or once in the configuration.h). I don't understand the waste of plastic. The square is designed as such that it prints very little material, just 2 nozzle widths for two layers. It is intended to actually print something, else you won't be able to measure the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Comment out your E values and the temp set/wait lines:

`...
M109 S245
M190 S120
...
G1 X123.113 Y95.644 E12.81357  F250
G1 X125.613 Y94.214 E13.06364 ; skirt
G1 X128.409 Y93.523 E13.31370 ; skirt
G1 X131.287 Y93.624 E13.56377 ; skirt
G1 X133.471 Y94.259 E13.76129     F250 
G1 X133.771 Y94.384 E13.78949 ; skirt
...`

Becomes:

`...
;M109 S245
;M190 S120
...
G1 X123.113 Y95.644 F250 ; E12.81357 
G1 X125.613 Y94.214 ; E13.06364 ; skirt
G1 X128.409 Y93.523 ; E13.31370 ; skirt
G1 X131.287 Y93.624 ; E13.56377 ; skirt
G1 X133.471 Y94.259 ; E13.76129     F250 
G1 X133.771 Y94.384 ; E13.78949 ; skirt
...`

Now the printer won't wait for any temperatures, and won't dispense any material.

Comment: You don't need to comment out the E values, if the extruder temperature is not set, and thus lower than the minimum extrusion temperature, the extruder stepper just won't turn (safety measure of Marlin). This means that only the bed heating and extruder heating needs to be commented out.